# Is it reasonable that a question can still be voted on after it's been closed?

Tags: feature-request, voting, closed-questions

In all the discussion about closing or downvoting bad questions, the focus is on questions that are still open. Once a question has been closed as a duplicate, is it really necessary to allow continued downvoting? Closed questions are technically "on hold" and the OP is invited to improve them. Shouldn't the question be immune to downvotes (and presumably upvotes) until it is edited or reopened?

The question is prompted by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395952/how-do-you-detect-keys-being-pressed-in-python) by a newby user. The question was downvoted a bit, then closed as a duplicate (with my help). So far, so good. But the question has continued to get downvotes (currently at -6), and the poor user is now at reputation 2.

I am aware that people sometimes pile on to downvoted questions. This is not even that bad a question: the goal is stated clearly, it's just missing OS information to be properly answerable. In short, it's the kind of duplicate that adds something to the site. Forcing the OP to close it doesn't seem like a good thing for anyone.

Comment: [Similar MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83798/why-allow-closed-questions-to-be-voted-on)

Comment: I'd looked but didn't find the duplicate questions before posting. Thanks everyone. (PS I _like_ the button that marks my own question as duplicate :-)

Comment: Is it reasonable that a question can still be upvoted after it's closed?

Comment: @JoshCaswell From the question, emphasis mine, "Shouldn't the question be immune to downvotes **(and presumably upvotes)**"

Comment: I did miss that, @Servy , thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By locking voting on closed posts you (in no particular order):

1. Prevent posts not currently at a score of -3 from getting to -3 to allow for immediate manual deletion by 20k users.
2. Prevent a post currently at a score at or below -3 from being voted above that point, to prevent immediate manual deletion by 20k users (say, if the post was salvaged in editing, or even if there isn't).
3. The same as the previous two points, but for the automatic cleanup scripts (which are also based on a different score).
4. Prevent the question from moving above or below a score of -3 which would impact whether it can show up on the homepage.  Bad questions above -3 couldn't get moved below it (so that others no longer need to see it) and those below it couldn't get bumped above it, even if they're being improved.
5. Prevent the feedback of all of the users seeing the question while it's closed from feeding the question ban algorithm.  This goes both ways, if the question is *really* bad, votes can't be cast to indicate this (thus impacting the decision of whether the user should be allowed to continue posting, or if they should be throttled); if it's off topic (or close worthy for another reason) but not a very bad question, votes can't be cast to indicate *that*.

Comment: That makes sense, especially if all voting is blocked... But still perhaps there could be a limit to how low the score can get? -3, or whatever gives all necessary information. Duplicates in particular shouldn't be downvoted to oblivion just for being duplicates...

Comment: @alexis If they're bad posts, their score should reflect that.  They shouldn't be prevented from having an accurate score just because they're duplicates.  And if you prevent the score from going below -3 then someone can come along and bump it to -2 on their own, even if 5 other people *would* have downvoted the post, putting it at -8, had their votes been accepted.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I guess the real problem is the piling-on behavior (but the thresholds presumably take it into account.) Good for question management, even if a bit drastic for the askers.

Comment: @alexis People shouldn't be prohibited from providing their feedback just because other people have also provided some feedback.  All people are allowed to cast their own votes how they see fit.

Comment: I don't mean legitimate feedback. By "piling on" I meant the well-known behavior where some people don't actually evaluate the question, but cast downvotes because the question has a lot of them, so it must be bad. Anyway, issue closed.

Comment: @alexis By "well known" I assume you mean, "frequently assumed by people with no basis whatsoever to that assumption."  I see no reason at all to assume that such behavior isn't *extremely* rare.  People just assume that the only reason people downvote posts *must* be inappropriate because that's easier than trying to find (and fix) an actual problem.

Comment: Well, I don't feel like looking through meta to see how well others back up their references to this, so you win. My own perspective is based on several cases (more than a half-dozen) that I considered clearly excessive and sometimes downright mistaken; but I've got nothing that would change your mind.

Comment: @alexis And I've seen many tens of thousands of questions downvoted because they're actually bad.  So tens of thousands vs. "several" sounds like pretty darn rare to me.  When we're talking hundredths of a percent, that's not exactly "common".